# How to save a class declared in a web service to file system

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services

I have a web service written in VB.NET where there is a  method declared in this way:

```
Public Function i1eTicketNew(Login As LoginInfo, Ticket As i1eNewTicketRequest) As i1eNewTicketResponse
```

When the method is called, I would like to save in the file system, the xml structure of the `class i1eNewTicketRequest`, for saving original request information.

Is there any easy way for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend XML serialization of the object (or binary serialization depending on your needs)

Since this is a web service, it is likely your class already implements IXmlSerializable, you can serialize it like so:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

Enjoy.